# Why vertex shader doesn't compile?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

Im kind of new to WebGl, but I wanted to try an example. I created my script like this:

#### Setup script

```js
import testVertexShader from './shaders/test/vertex.glsl'
import testFragmentShader from './shaders/test/fragment.glsl'
// Debug
const gui = new dat.GUI()

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

/**
 * Textures
 */
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
const dialTexture = textureLoader.load('/textures/textureD.png')

/**
 * Test mesh
 */
// Geometry
const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(3, 1, 100, 100)


// Material
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: testVertexShader,
    fragmentShader: testFragmentShader,
    uniforms:
    {
        uTime: { value: 0 },
        uTexture: { value: dialTexture }
    }
})

// Mesh
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(mesh)

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
{
    // Update sizes
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight

    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
})

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
scene.add(camera)

// Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
controls.enableDamping = true

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

/**
 * Animate
 */
const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () =>
{
    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

    // Update material
    material.uniforms.uTime.value = elapsedTime

    // Update controls
    controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick();
```

And my shaders like this:

#### VERTEX

```c
varying vec2 vUv;
uniform float uTime;

void main()
{
    vUv = uv;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelPosition * vec4(position, 1.0);;
}
```

#### FRAGMENT

```c
uniform float uTime;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;

varying vec2 vUv;


void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(uTexture, vUv);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

But I keep getting this error in the console and I don't know why :(

```
Three.module.js:19006 THREE.WebGLProgram: Shader Error 0 - VALIDATE_STATUS false

Program Info Log: Vertex shader is not compiled.

VERTEX

ERROR: 0:64: 'modelPosition' : undeclared identifier


  59: 
  60: void main()
  61: {
  62:     vUv = uv;
  63: 
> 64:     gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelPosition * vec4(position, 1.0);;
```

Can you give me a hint?

I consoled log the vertex shader and it appears, but I cannot compile it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [WebGLProgram](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram). The uniform variable `modelPosition` does not exist, but `modelMatrix` does, which is the model transformation matrix and contains the position, orientation and scaling of the 3D mesh.

```js
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```